# writing Average function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

1) I am trying to write function that computes the average of three numbers
I wrote something like

```
average :: (Float,Float,Float) -> Float 
average x y z = (x+y+z)/3
```

but it wouldn't work for some reason

can someone guide me how to write a function that takes 3 numbers and compute their average ?

2 ) I got this average function from a textbook but when i tried to run it

```
    average :: [Int] -> Rational
    average [] = error "empty list"
    average xs = toRational (sum xs) / toRational(length xs)
```

for example if I entered average [1..5] in the compiler
the output become 
3 % 1 , it doesn't print the average of the values.

Comment: The first function should be `average (x, y, z) = ..` or `average :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float`. The second function does work.. the average of `[1..5]` is actually 3. The rational number 3 is printed as `3 % 1` (or 3 over 1) in Haskell.

Comment: @user2407038 That's an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are two different ways you could write a function of 3 numbers:

   - a function with 3 parameters, each parameter 1 number
   - a function with 1 parameter, the parameter is 3 numbers (a *tuple* of 3 numbers)

   Either is fine, but you are mixing them.

   a) 3 parameters:

   ```
   average_3_params :: Float -> (Float -> (Float -> Float))
   average_3_params x y z = (x+y+z)/3
   ```

   How to read this is: `average_3_params` is a function from a `Float` to a function of 2 parameters, and so on (note that the parenthesis in the type are optional, I'm just being pedantic. `Float -> Float -> Float -> Float` is equivalent).

   b) Tuple parameter

   ```
   average_tuple :: (Float, Float, Float) -> Float 
   average_tuple (x, y, z) = (x+y+z)/3
   ```

   Here, the function has a single parameter, but that parameter contains 3 `Float`s and we use *pattern matching* to extract the primitive values.
2. `3 % 1` is the average of `[1..5]`. Note that your function returns a `Rational`, not a `Float`. A `Rational` is a fraction: read the `%` as a division bar.

A couple side notes. While a) seems a bit odd at first, it turns out to be very handy as it gives you partial application (currying) for free. Regarding `Float`, you should probably be using `Double` [0].

[0] https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Floating_point